# cómo buscar y ordenar en un dataTables jquery sin que se interfieran

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, dropdownlist, tablerowsorter

Tengo una tabla creada con dataTables en jquery. Las columnas de pais ciudad e idioma tienen un dropdownlist y un icono para ordenar de mayor a menor. Estas dos funcionalidades deben estar disponibles para esas columnas. He creado el código para filtrar con la seleccion del dropdown y para ordenar con el atributo "orderable" de las columnas. El filtrado y el ordenamiento funciona correctamente pero el problema es que cuando selecciono el dropdownlist porque automáticamente se cambia el orden de los datos... es decir, si la columna país esta ordenada de mayor a menor y selecciono el dropdown el país se reordena de menor a mayor automáticamente y viceversa. Quiero que se reordene únicamente cuando presione los triángulos de reordenamiento y que cuando use el dropdown unicamente se filtre.

¿Alguna idea? gracias!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.4/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.4/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
          
</head>
<body>
    <table id="miTabla" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Edad</th>
      <th>Peso</th>
      <th>
        <select id="filtro-pais" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <option value="">Todos los países</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th>
        <select id="filtro-ciudad" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <option value="">Todas las ciudades</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th>
        <select id="filtro-idioma" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <option value="">Todos los idiomas</option>
        </select>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody> 
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>


{
  // Definir arrays de datos
  let nombres = ["Ana", "Benito", "Cristina", "Diego", "Elena", "Fernando", "Gisela", "Hugo", "Inés", "Juan", "Karla", "Luis", "Marta", "Nicolás", "Olivia", "Pedro", "Quirino", "Renata", "Santiago", "Teresa", "Ulises", "Valentina", "Ximena", "Yolanda", "Zoe"];
  let edades = [25, 38, 41, 19, 57, 29, 33, 44, 52, 46, 22, 34, 48, 26, 30, 37, 43, 59, 27, 39, 31, 36, 49, 51, 28];
  let pesos = [60, 75, 68, 72, 63, 80, 85, 69, 70, 77, 73, 71, 79, 65, 67, 76, 74, 62, 78, 64, 82, 81, 66, 72, 68];
  let paises = ["México", "Argentina", "Colombia", "Chile", "Perú", "España", "Estados Unidos", "Brasil", "Uruguay", "Venezuela"];
  let ciudades = ["Ciudad de México", "Buenos Aires", "Bogotá", "Santiago", "Lima", "Madrid", "Nueva York", "São Paulo", "Montevideo", "Caracas"];
  let idiomas = ["Español", "Inglés", "Portugués", "Francés", "Alemán", "Italiano", "Mandarín", "Japonés", "Coreano", "Ruso"];

  var tusDatos = [];

  // Generar datos aleatorios
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let nombre = nombres[Math.floor(Math.random() * nombres.length)];
    let edad = edades[Math.floor(Math.random() * edades.length)];
    let peso = pesos[Math.floor(Math.random() * pesos.length)];
    let pais = paises[Math.floor(Math.random() * paises.length)];
    let ciudad = ciudades[Math.floor(Math.random() * ciudades.length)];
    let idioma = idiomas[Math.floor(Math.random() * idiomas.length)];

    tusDatos.push({"Nombre":nombre, "Edad":edad, "Peso":peso, "País":pais, "Ciudad":ciudad, "Idioma":idioma});
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //var tusDatos = [  {    "Nombre": "Juan",    "Edad": 28,    "Peso": 70,    "País": "México",    "Ciudad": "Ciudad de México",    "Idioma": "Español"  },  {    "Nombre": "Mary",    "Edad": 32,    "Peso": 55,    "País": "Estados Unidos",    "Ciudad": "Nueva York",    "Idioma": "Inglés"  },  {    "Nombre": "Satoshi",    "Edad": 25,    "Peso": 60,    "País": "Japón",    "Ciudad": "Tokio",    "Idioma": "Japonés"  }];
  tabla = $('#miTabla').DataTable({
    initComplete: function () {
      this.api().columns([0, 3, 4]).every(function () {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
          .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
          .on('change', function () {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
              $(this).val()
            );

            column
              .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
          select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
        });
      });
    },    
    data: tusDatos,
        columns: [
    { data: "Nombre", orderable: true },
    { data: "Edad", orderable: true },
    { data: "Peso", orderable: true },
    { data: "País", orderable: true },
    { data: "Ciudad", orderable: true },
    { data: "Idioma", orderable: true }
    ],    
  });

  // Llenar dropdownlist de países
  var paises = tabla.column(3).data().unique();

  $('#filtro-pais').append('<option value="">Todos los países</option>');
  paises.each(function(value, index) {
      $('#filtro-pais').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
      console.log(index, ':', value);
  });

  // Llenar dropdownlist de ciudades
  var ciudades = tabla.column(4).data().unique();
  $('#filtro-ciudad').append('<option value="">Todas las ciudades</option>');
  ciudades.each(function(value, index) {
      $('#filtro-ciudad').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
  });

  // Llenar dropdownlist de idiomas
  var idiomas = tabla.column(5).data().unique();
  $('#filtro-idioma').append('<option value="">Todos los idiomas</option>');
  idiomas.each(function(value, index) {
      $('#filtro-idioma').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
  });  

  $('#filtro-pais, #filtro-ciudad, #filtro-idioma').on('change', function() {
    var pais = $('#filtro-pais').val();
    var ciudad = $('#filtro-ciudad').val();
    var idioma = $('#filtro-idioma').val();

    tabla.column(3).search(pais).draw();
    tabla.column(4).search(ciudad).draw();
    tabla.column(5).search(idioma).draw();
  });  


  
  
});



</script>


</body>
</html>
```